# How to loop a on window load Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, settimeout

I have this function set up on a window scroll listener , i have tried to set the timeout on is to recall it but as of yet i cant seem to get it to fire, any ideas, thanks in advance!

```
// functions:
var $delayAnimate = function(el, time, effect) {
  el.delay(time)
    .queue(function(next) {
      $(this).addClass(effect);
      next();
    });
};

// function for multi animations
var multiAnimations = function(el, setTime, ef) {
  var i = 0;
  el.each(function (key, value) {
    i = i + setTime;
    $delayAnimate($(this), i, ef);
  });
};

// load on window height
var onWindowAnimate = function (h, el, setTime, ef) {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > h) {
    // call multi animations function
    multiAnimations(el, setTime, ef);
  }
};

// get img's
var $affiliateSection = $("#aff-img > li > img");
$(window).scroll(function () {
  onWindowAnimate(200, $affiliateSection, 300, 'subtlefadeIn');
});
```

Comment: Please explain more on this

Comment: it is going through 3 other function which are // load on window height // function for multi animations // function to slow down animations..... so i need to to keep firing, at the moment it only fire once on window scroll event listener

Comment: We just see a function which is called on scroll event. But we don't know what that function does and why it does not fire or does not work.

Comment: Can you show some more code including HTML

Comment: `$(window).on('load scroll resize', function() { onWindowAnimate(200, $affiliateSection, 300, 'subtlefadeIn');
});` ???

Comment: Do you want to execute your function at page load like if you do scroll on the page automatically?

Comment: the functions work fine, just need to settimeout on that last $(window).scroll event listener,....any ideas?

Comment: what is the problem? you want to stop the animation when scroll event is fired again before it is ended?

Comment: @user3358014 But wait, this completly unclear **what is the question???** Read your 'question' again, do you understand it yourself?

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to understand what you want, but if I am right...

Just a timeout:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        onWindowAnimate(200, $affiliateSection, 300, 'subtlefadeIn');
    }, 1000);
});
```

If you want to wait for each timeout to end before start the new one:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'AnimationTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'AnimationTimer', setTimeout(function () {
        onWindowAnimate(200, $affiliateSection, 300, 'subtlefadeIn');
    }, 1000));
});
```

Comment: I think OP is talking about `$delayAnimate`, but who knows?... ;)